# Android programming define new variable using old?

Tags: java, android, variables

How can I define a new variable with an old one in java in Android? I'm talking about the part of this code that has strings `to, message, subject` and then some placeholding names to the right of the equals sign. I need to know how to change the values such as `textSubject` etc to a relevant variable previously defined. When I outright replace them, it doesnt work for some reason.

Also, I can't figure out why it won't take the onClick method right before that. Here is the code.

```
public class RefillActivity extends Activity {
    public String name;
    public String birthday;
    public String prescriptionOptions;
    public String notes;
    public String number;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.refill_activity_main);
    sendRefillRequest();
    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSendRefillRequest);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String to = textTo.getText().toString();
            String message = textMessage.getText().toString();
            String subject = name.getText().toString();

            Intent mEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            mEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"test@example.com"});
            mEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            mEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

            // prompts to choose email client
            mEmail.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mEmail, "Choose an email client to send your feedback!"));
            }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.refill, menu);
    return true;
}
public void sendRefillRequest(){
    final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
    name = nameField.getText().toString();
    final EditText birthdayField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextBirthday);
    birthday =  birthdayField.getText().toString();
    final EditText numberField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextPrescriptionNumber);
    number = numberField.getText().toString();
    final Spinner prescriptionOptions = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerPrescriptionOptions);
    this.prescriptionOptions = prescriptionOptions.getSelectedItem().toString();
    final EditText notesField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextSpecialNotes);
    notes = notesField.getText().toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are defining your variables as local variables to those methods. Make them member variables

```
public class RefillActivity extends Activity {
public String name;
public String birthday;
public String prescriptionOptions;
public String notes;
public String number;

 EditText nameField;     // define them here
EditText birthdayField; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.refill_activity_main);
    sendRefillRequest();
    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSendRefillRequest);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
```

Define them as member variables then you can initialize them in `sendRefillRequest()` and you will have access to them

Also, in your `sendRefillRequest()` method, define the `String` variables as `final` and you will have access to them in your `onClick`

If this doesn't fix your issue with "... why it won't take the onClick method..." then please be a little more specific about that. What is/isn't it doing? Do you put breakpoints in there to see if it is entered when you click your `Button`?

Comment: Those weren't the variables I meant, they seem to be working fine

Comment: Then which variables are you talking about? The way it looks to me, you don't have access to them in your `onClick` right now

Comment: Well I was talking about the strings defined in onClick, but now that you mention it, I see the issue with what you're saying. So I have issues both places. When I defined the ones at the top as you described, however, Android Studio doesn't recognize them.

Comment: Then that is a separate issue. My answer will solve your current issues as far as java and Android go. Now you are having an Android Studio issue which I have just begun to dabble with a little. The documentation even says that you may not want to use that alone if you aren't very experienced as it is a pre-release version and very buggy. You may consider using Eclipse or something similar as your primary IDE until Android Studio is more mature

Comment: Well I started this project in studio, how do I import it to Eclipse? Is that a straightforward process?

Comment: Probably, I haven't done it that way but I have imported from Eclipse to Android Studio. If it seems difficult, you can copy the project from wherever it is stored and paste to your workspace then just create new project from existing source in Eclipse

Comment: I made your suggested changes with the variables, but AS says they're not recognized. Should I be using "nameField" like you say? Or something else? And should I be putting "String" before "EditText"?

Comment: My changes shouldn't give you that error. No, definitely don't have `String` before `EditText`. I don't know what variables its giving you that error on but my suggestions wouldn't cause that. You need to copy your project into Eclipse or another IDE and try it there